# Contact groups in 2.3.4 - xperia?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sony-ericsson-xperia-neo

Is there a way to have contact groups in this phone?
I know it is possible on other phones, but this one does not give you the ability to make them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 4.x supports contact groups. This is the only way I've found till now.